# java.net.UnknownHostException: www.google.co.in - error with JMeter 3

Tags: jmeter

I'm using `JMeter 3` for Firefox browser. I have changed the proxy settings as `localhost , 8080`. Then I'm trying to record. but I'm getting below error. Would you please let me know why this issue is coming. Do I need to change settings ?

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: www.google.co.in
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
```

Comment: Try using [Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-Chrome-Extension).

Answer (score 3):

This error usually indicates that your browser is not able to connect the Internet via JMeter's proxy. Usually it happens when you're sitting behind a corporate proxy and your host doesn't have direct Internet access.

Try figuring out your corporate proxy details and provide them to JMeter via command-line arguments:

- Launch JMeter providing several proxy-related command line arguments, to wit

  ```
  -H, --proxyHost <argument>
          Set a proxy server for JMeter to use
  -P, --proxyPort <argument>
          Set proxy server port for JMeter to use
  -N, --nonProxyHosts <argument>
          Set nonproxy host list (e.g. *.apache.org|localhost)
  -u, --username <argument>
          Set username for proxy server that JMeter is to use
  -a, --password <argument>
          Set password for proxy server that JMeter is to use
  ```
- Alternatively you can configure proxy server details in *system.properties* file like:

  ```
  http.proxyHost=your_corporate_proxy_server
  http.proxyPort=your_corporate_proxy_port
  https.proxyHost=your_corporate_proxy_server
  https.proxyPort=your_corporate_proxy_port
  ```

  or pass them via -D command line arguments like:

  ```
  jmeter -Dhttp.proxyHost=your_corporate_server ...
  ```

  You will need to restart JMeter to pick these properties up.

See:

- [Using JMeter behind a proxy](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: Hi Dimitri, thanks for the useful info. We are working on Ubantu machine, are there any commands through which i can achieve proper connectivity.